# SQLITE - IF Statement Inside Trigger Error

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I had just started taking MySQL class and in one of my assignment, I need to create a trigger inside an Sqlite that enables update commands to be executed on view called JordanFriend. This update should also propagate to the Highschooler tables. The update does not allow to take grades out of the 9-12 range.

I keep running into errors with my triggers and not sure what is wrong with it.

Here is my Trigger:

```
delimiter $$ 

CREATE TRIGGER `grade_update_check` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `highschooler`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.GRADE > 12) 
THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE;
END IF;
IF (NEW.GRADE < 9) 
THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE;
END IF; 
IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM highschooler WHERE name = NEW.name and grade = NEW.grade) = 1 
THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE; 
END IF; 
END $$

delimiter ;
```

And this is the errors that I keep getting when I try to create this trigger:

```
sqlite> delimiter $$ 
   ...> 
   ...> CREATE TRIGGER `grade_update_check` 
   ...> BEFORE UPDATE ON `highschooler`
   ...> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   ...> IF (NEW.GRADE > 12) 
   ...> THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE;
Error: near "delimiter": syntax error
sqlite> END IF;
Error: near "IF": syntax error
sqlite> IF (NEW.GRADE < 9) 
   ...> THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE;
Error: near "IF": syntax error
sqlite> END IF; 
Error: near "IF": syntax error
sqlite> IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM highschooler WHERE name = NEW.name and grade = NEW.grade) = 1 
   ...> THEN SET NEW.GRADE = OLD.GRADE; 
Error: near "IF": syntax error
sqlite> END IF; 
Error: near "IF": syntax error
sqlite> END $$
   ...> 
   ...> delimiter ;
Error: near "$$": syntax error
```

Any help or advice would be appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and SQLite are different software products and they have different syntax and usage.

In this case, you don't need to use `delimiter` in SQLite. That's a thing specific to the MySQL client, to help the parser from getting confused between `;` after each statement in the body of the trigger, versus the `;` that ends the whole CREATE TRIGGER statement.

SQLite doesn't need `delimiter` because their client's parser can tell the difference. It knows if the `;` is inside the body of a trigger.

Read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html for examples of creating triggers in SQLite.